# I have a problem with multiple image uploader

Tags: laravel

I have a problem with multiple image uploader, when I upload images one by one it,s successfully showing on the pop but the problem is that the file picker picks the last image instead of all,

please check the image preview here

[image]

**Note:-**  I am getting only the last image in the request when I submit the form.

**dd($request->all());**

```
array:10 [▼
  "_token" => "7Sshgb1UTGudcbrxzIjvoE05UAJAF48MSpqUpHzP"
  "order_name" => "dfgfdg"
  "height" => "44"
  "width" => "44"
  "order_placement" => "Cap Side"
  "required_format" => null
  "order_fabric" => "Blanket"
  "instruction" => "fgfdg"
  "customRadioInline1" => "OFF"
  "image" => array:1 [▼
    0 => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#345 ▶}
  ]
]
```

**HTML view**

```
                      <div class="mb-3 d-flex justify-content-between mt-4">
                        <div class="upload_file_wrapper">
                          <button>Choose Files</button>
                          <input type="file"  name="image[]"   id="upload_files" 
                          multiple/>
                        </div>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data- 
                             dismiss="modal">Okay</button>
                    </div>
```

**script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  
    $("#upload_files").change(function (e) {
        // readURL(this);

        var jamo = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
      
        $('#upload-preview').attr('src', jamo);

        var imgpath = document.getElementById('upload_files');
        if (!imgpath.value == "") {
            var img = imgpath.files[0].size;
            var imgsize = img / 1024;
            var imgsizeN = imgsize.toFixed(2);
        }

        var fileName = e.target.files[0].name;
        $('.file_list').append(`
        <p class="image_data" src="${jamo}"> ${imgsizeN} kb / ${fileName} </p>
        `);

        var file = (e.srcElement || e.target).files[0];
        console.log(file);
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.image_data', function () {
        var getSrc = $(this).attr('src');
        $('#upload-preview').attr('src', getSrc);
    });

    $('#upload_files').on('change', function() {
       
        var formData = new FormData();
        var files = $('#upload_files').files;
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
          formData.append('image[]', files[i]);
        }    
      });

});
```

Comment: Do you select multiple images in one file picker popup (selecting files while holding shift or control key), or do you click "choose files" multiple times and then hit submit? (I understand that you're not clicking submit after each pick)

Comment: after selecting the shift button when I upload images it's successfully showing all images in request but I don't want to do that I want to do that when I upload images one by one file picker should pick all images instead of last image thank u.

Comment: Native file pickers don't support that, it will only upload the files from the latest selection. In that case you'll have to submit the form or send an AJAX request with selected files on each `change` event of file input.